# External JS File Will Not Connect to JSP Page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-mvc

OK, so I am working on a small application.  I have CSS and JS directly on my JSP page.  Earlier in the week, I decided to create external pages for both to create a cleaner page. I created them both under WebContent/CSS (or in the case of the JS /JS) and the file name.

I am doing this in Eclipse, and I had problems connecting the CSS at first. I was able to find out the location eclipse was taken by setting the source to "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/mycssfile.css  I then took the value I found in the source code on the page, popped it in there since errors were being thrown due to the usage of the pageContext code, and it worked for the CSS.

Then I went to do the same thing for the JS.

The JS is primarily working as a front end validator, so if it's not working I have a back end validator (I'm using spring mvc) that picks up the errors.

I have tried doing the pageContext thing again, no avail.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c: url value="/myPlayApp/js/myjavascriptfile.js"/>"> </script>
```

That also did not work.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/myPlayApp/js/myjavascriptfile.js"> </script>
```

This did not either.

The JS code will function perfectly if I put it within Script tags in the page.

I have set alerts as a debugging method to see if it's getting into the file, and it's not even doing that.

Any idea of what I can change on the import, or is there something else I must be doing?

Comment: is /myPlayApp/js/myjavascriptfile.js definitely the right path?

Comment: Yes, I used the contextPath to figure that out.  It for some reason completely ignores the WebContent file and just grabs at the JS or CSS.

Comment: Input "yourdomain/myPlayApp/js/myjavascriptfile.js" in the address bar of the browser and see if the file is being served. Also checking the network activity on some browsers' debugger can give the answer.